# Split an array into a string to send bulk sms codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I have a function used to send SMS and it works nice. This is the function I use:

```
function send_sms() {
        $acc = $this->input->post('acc');
        $key = $this->input->post('key');
        $to = $this->input->post('to');
        $sms = $this->input->post('sms');

        $url = "http://host.com/public/sms.api?acc=". $acc ."&key=". $key ."&to=". $to ."&sms=" . $sms;

        $this->load->helper('html');

        echo link_tag($url);
        echo 'SMS Sent, thank you';
    }
```

Now, I want to send SMS to more than one numbers. And the numbers are getting from my database. But the message didn't arrive to my number.

This is the function to send bulk SMS I have:

```
function send_bulk_sms() {
        $search_by = $this->input->post('search_by');

    if ($search_by == 'prefer_location') {
        $location = $this->input->post('search_field');
        $recipients_array = $this->company_model->search_by_location($location);

        $recipients = array();
        foreach ($recipients_array as $key => $value) {
            $recipients[] = $value['phone'];
        }
    } elseif ($search_by == 'sector') {
        $sector = $this->input->post('search_field');
        $recipients_array = $this->company_model->search_by_sector($sector);

        $recipients = array();
        foreach ($recipients_array as $key => $value) {
            $recipients[] = $value['phone'];
        }
    }

    $acc = $this->input->post('acc');
    $key = $this->input->post('key');
    $to = $recipients;
    $sms = $this->input->post('sms');

    $url = "http://host.com/public/sms.api?acc=" . $acc . "&key=" . $key . "&to=" . $to . "&sms=" . $sms;

    $this->load->helper('html');

    echo link_tag($url);
    echo 'SMS Sent, thank you';
}
```

The `$recipients` value from the database looks like this:

> Array ( [0] => 03-56122223 [1] => 02158745 )

I have tried to change the `$to` value like this:

```
$to = array(
            '02158745',
            '02158745'
        );
```

or like this

```
$to = array(
            02158745,
            02158745
        );
```

Both of them didn't work. It works when I tried to change `$to` value like this:

```
$to = '02158745';
```

Is there any solution to split the array value into a string?
Or how to send the SMS one by one with the numbers are from `$recipients`?

Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you loop through your array and call your `send_sms()` function for each number?

Comment: I think it depends on the SMS service provider you are using. The format to specify multiple sms  will be in their developer docs.

Comment: Does the provider of the API support you passing an array? You can't just decide what you want to pass them. See their API documentation. Perhaps they have a DIFFERENT API for bulk SMS

Comment: yes, the SMS service can send multiple SMS. But when I tried, it doesn't work. Any sugestion?

Comment: to 
  
= 
   [required] 
  The 
  mobile 
  number 
  recipient(s). 
  Can 
  be 
  of 
  multiple 
  inputs 
  
separated 
  by 
  comma 
  (,). 
  
Value 
  examples: 
  0123456789, 
  012-­‐3456789, 
  +0123456789, 
  +012-­‐3456789. This one is on the documentation, but it doesn't work.

Comment: There you go, so instead of passing `$to` as an array, pass it as a comma seperated list: `$to = implode(',', $to);`

Comment: Its not really worthy. Feel free to post the answer yourself, reference your SMS provider's documentation.

Answer (score 0):

try array walk function - [Apply a user function to every member of an array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php)

```
$to = array(
        02158745,
        02158745
    );

array_walk($to, 'send_sms');

function send_sms($to,$key) {
    $acc = $this->input->post('acc');
    $key = $this->input->post('key');
    $to = $this->input->post('to');
    $sms = $this->input->post('sms');

    $url = "http://host.com/public/sms.api?acc=". $acc ."&key=". $key ."&to=". $to ."&sms=" . $sms;
    $this->load->helper('html');

    echo link_tag($url);

}
```